# In React Query, How to get data if i'm using two mutate functions in a component?

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm on a component where a api call exists on componentdidmount and one when use clicks on a button of that page so how can get the data of that particular api call?

```
const [mutate, { data, error }] = useMutation(handlefunction);
componentDidMount(){
mutate({api:api, data:{email:"email});
}
return(
<button onClick = {()=>{mutate({api:api2, data:{}})}>click</button>
}
```

how can i get data for button click mutate?

Answer (score 0):

```
onClickHandler = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   mutate({api:api2, data:{}})
}
```

In return function:

```
<button onClick = {onClickHandler}>click</button>
```